# Error on SharePoint calculated field

Tags: sharepoint

I need some guidance on creation of a calculated field column...

I have two columns that should dictate the value in this calculated field

TCV and F01

```
F01 = No the field is blank
F01 = Yes and TCV GT or = 25000000 the field = CEO/COO
F01 = Yes and TCV < 25000000 the field = BG Group


=IF(F01="Yes",[TCV]>25000000,"CEO/COO","BG Team")
```

Answer (score 2):

=IF(F01="No","",IF(F01="Yes",IF(TCV>=25000000,"CEO/COO","Business Group")))